Meaning/origin of the German term "Schließungssatz"
Certain theorems in geometry are called Schließungssatz in German, like the theorem of Desargues and the theorem of Pappos, see for example this German wikipedia page.
I wonder what the (historical?) reason is for the part Schließung.
The German verb schließen has at least two possible meanings:

to deduce, so it would be "deducing theorem" which is kind of redundant. But maybe it is for historical reasons.
to close. Maybe the background is that the theorem guarantees some kind of "closedness" of the geometrical constellation, like three points being collinear in the case of Desargues and Pappos.

But these are only my personal guesses. Does anyone have a more profound explanation?
Addition
There is the term closure theorem in English. However, my impression from an internet search is that the English closure theorem is used exclusively in Poncelet's closure theorem. This theorem can be interpreted that some sequences of linked line segments literally close, meaning that after a certain number of steps, you get back to the starting point.
Poncelet's closure theorem is also called Schließungssatz in German, and the German wikipedia article states "Der Satz ist das Paradebeispiel für eine Klasse geometrischer Probleme, die Schließungsprobleme genannt werden." ("The theorem is the prime example of a class of geometric problems called closure problems.")
So maybe Poncelet's theorem is the source of the term closure theorem in English and Schließungssatz in German. Unlike Enlish, the German term Schließungssatz got applied to a wider variety of geometric theorems of "similar flair". But again, this is only my private theory.

The form "Schließungssatz" is rather poorly compatible with the interpretation as "deducing theorem"; my sensibilities as a native speaker would expect the form "Schlusssatz" in this case (a deduction is a "Schluss," whereas "Schließung" corresponds more or less to the English "closing" as in "closing of a store," say). Evidence for the second interpretation is also provided by this Wikipedia section which defines what it means to "take the projective closure of an affine plane" ("eine affine Ebene projektiv abschließen").

@BenSteffan thanks for input. I'm pretty sure that the projective closure "projektiver Abschluss" is not the origin of "Schließung" in "Schließungssatz" ("projektive Abschließung" would also be kind of strange...).

@BenSteffan Thinking again, the term "Schließung" feels strange to me, too (I'm native German). But this is not exclusive to the "deduce" approach, it's the same in the "close" setting. Something with "...schluss" feels better in all cases. Maybe some ancient language usage is the source. Geometry is one of the oldest roots of mathematics.

@azimut -- how about closure theorem?

@m-stgt thanks for the pointer. I've added a few lines on "closure theorem" to my question. (Just in case: My question was not for the English translation of "Schließungssatz", but for an explanation why the theorems of Dersargues and Pappos are called "Schließungssatz" in German.)

If you don't manage to get an answer here, you might try asking over at the HSM Stack Exchange.

@Semiclassical ok, see https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/18120/16951 We'll see if it makes a difference.
